# Fossil SCM in Windows, how to make timeline accessible in LAN?

Tags: windows, version-control, localhost, fossil

I have run the Fossil-SCM web interface for timeline of my project at port 8080 using the command

```
fossil.exe ui
```

I'm connected to a LAN, my IP is 192.168.137.11 and I want to access the timeline from the IP 192.168.137.8

When I try to open 192.168.137.11:8080 in browser from .8 pc I'm getting page not found error. But when I try the following I'm getting some response.

```
ping 192.168.137.11
```

Help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [command-line help](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help/ui) for the `fossil ui` command:

```
The "ui" command automatically starts a web browser after initializing
the web server.  The "ui" command also binds to 127.0.0.1 and so will
only process HTTP traffic from the local machine.
```

Since you're trying to access fossil from another computer than the local machine, that won't work. Instead, you should use the command `fossil server`. Then it will bind to all available IP addresses, and accept connections from other machines on the network.

(The only other difference between `fossil server` and `fossil ui` is that the latter will launch a web browser with the home page for the current project, whereas `fossil server` won't do that).